# How to merge between two arrays by index

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays .. first array like this :

```
$questions = [
    "type" => "form",
    "controls" => []
];
```

and second array is filled by foreach loop like this :

```
$count = 0;
foreach($x as $y){
    $controls [
        "id" => $y.$count,
        "id2" => $y.$count+1,
    ]

    $count++;
}
```

I want to merge all values from the second array to `controls` index from first array

any help please

Comment: Could you give an expected input and expected output please

Comment: You are missing a semicolon **;** on the second array after **]**

Comment: You have invalid syntax for `$controls` in the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Do you mean `$controls[] = [...];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to merge, just put the result directly into the location you want them in the loop

```
$questions = [
        "type" => "form",
        "controls" => []
    ];   

$count = 0;
foreach($x as $y){
    $questions['controls'][] =  ["id" => $y.$count,
                                 "id2" => $y.$count+1];
    $count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do:

```
$questions['controls'] = $controls;
```

You also need to fix your syntax for filling in `$controls`, it should be:

```
$controls[] = [
    "id" => $y.$count,
    "id2" => $y.$count+1,
];
```